# error: cannot convert ‘int (^)(int)’ to ‘R (^)(T)’ in initialization

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to understand how to best make use of blocks in my templated class.
I have the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
class MyClass {
public:
   typedef R (^Block)(T);

   MyClass(Block blk) {}
};

void testMyClass() {
    MyClass<int,int>::Block blk(^(int arg) {
        return 1 + arg;
    });
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error message:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (^)(int)’ to ‘R (^)(T)’ in initialization
```

Am I missing something obvious? Am I trying to do something that is not allowed? GCC accepts the program if I do the same thing without templates.

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it's not C++.

Comment: Blocks is a language extension, if that is what you mean.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this isn't C++.

Comment: Can a C++ with compiler-specific extensions still be called C++? I don't know.

Comment: Rolled back the tag removal. Apple's blocks extension **can** be used by GCC to build a C++ project.

Comment: What is the meaning of `^(int arg)`?

Comment: Could you pass the block type into the template instead of return and argument types?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The example was much simplified and I am extending a much larger class.

Comment: @AdamMaras: Even if it can be used to build C++ apps, the code in the example is not C++, and neither is the question. I've re-removed the tag.

Comment: @Bavarious: There's a difference between a language extension and a different language. I would remove the C++ tag from a question containing C++/CLI, for instance. If there's a language or platform specific extension (E.g. Windows or POSIX) then I'll usually add an appropriate tag for that as that's still C++. As a general rule, when something is a completely different language, even if it's based on C++, it should not be tagged with C++. In C++, ^ is never associated with a type; therefore this would qualify as a different language.

Comment: @Bavarious objective-c++ is a more fully qualified language name anyway. As long as that is there BillyONeal's edit is fine I think.

Comment: @BillyONeal Would you care to share your opinion on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112525/156620)? I’ll remove my comments here to avoid clutter.

Comment: Per the discussion on Meta, I've once again rolled back to Revision 1 to include the C++ tag and remove the Objective-C++ tag. This is clearly not an Objective-C++ question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue in GCC. I tested your program under LLVM 3 and it compiled just fine.

There are a number of problems in GCC 4.2's implementation of blocks, sometimes they can be worked around by fully qualifying your block declarations `^int(int arg){return 1 + arg;}` but in this case it was unable to work around this issue. I would highly recommend moving to use LLVM/Clang for any further work with Obj-C Blocks. Its C++ support is very good these days, especially for C++03 support.

Comment: Thanks! I know it copiles with clang++ and I suspected it was a compiler issue, but I hoped for some kind of workaround. I will switch to clang eventually, but other issues are preventing me ATM.